# "Content-Type" in header is not changing

Tags: php, http-headers, download, rest

I'm trying to call Rest web service with cURL that does next:

1. generate certificate
2. download this certificate

Every one of those functions is working alone, but when gathering them in one service the download dialog is not opening, and I'm always getting text/html as Content type, I saw it via Firebug.

This is the code of the downloading (from php.ent):

```
 if (file_exists($filename)) {
            header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $certName);

            readfile($filename, false);
            exit();
        }
```

and here's how I'm calling my service:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$dat=array( 
 // many args
            );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dat);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
    if ($curl_errno > 0) {
       echo "cURL Error ($curl_errno): $curl_error\n";
    } else {
       echo "Data received: $data\n";
   }
    curl_close($ch);
```

What's wrong guys?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your browser makes an HTTP request
2. Your server runs a PHP script that runs cURL
3. cURL gets data from another server and ignores the Content-Disposition header because it is cURL and not a browser
4. The PHP script running cURL outputs `Data received: $data` as the body of an HTML document
5. The browser receives that HTTP document

If you want the cURL using program to act as a proxy, then you need to proxy the HTTP headers and not add extra data to the output.